# Creating Isolines from point Data

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, shapefile, convert, point

I'm quite new with ArcGis 10 so I’m having difficulties with something that may be simple to some. Anyway I have a list of bores that I’ve plotted using coordinates. Now I need to draw a single contour line joining the bore points by their conductivity levels. As fair as I’ve tried researching I need to convert the shapefile of the bore details to a raster file and then create a contour line with the Spatial Analyst. Is this the correct procedure? I'm having real trouble trying to figure it all out.
I've tried creating a raster file but not sure which cell assignment type etc to choose. Every time I try creating a point raster file based on the conductivity, I don’t get all the information or there are no visible points. 
Could anyone shine a light on this for me and provide some help to the steps I may need to follow. I hope I’ve supplied enough information. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The short answer involves [interpolation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Interpolation_tools/009z00000069000000/) or [kriging](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_introduction_to_interpolation_methods/003100000008000000/) and then applying the [contour](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Contouring_works/009z000000vq000000/) tool of choice.
[Here is a video of creating surface.](http://video.arcgis.com/watch/2020/creating-surfaces)