# Drawing Contours using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, contour

Could you explain step by step of creating contours in ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop?

Starting from data input (also I need explanation on the type of data format ) to finally drawing the contours.

Comment: Start here: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00q8000000q5000000 Also related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41711/ Your question is a bit broad. Would help to describe what data you have to start with, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

[here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALSb7qPx8Qg) for ArcGIS 10 on contours that should help.  You need to use a DEM as an input. It is a raster file.

Answer (score 1):

You can start reading about it here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00q8000000q5000000